# Prevent alert tone when scanning / identifying an NFC intent

Tags: samsung-galaxy-nexus, nfc, alerts

Perhaps I'm missing something but when I scan an NFC tag via a Galaxy Nexus, the phone always makes the default alert tone.

Is there a way of switching this off? I have scoured the menus / preferences and can't find a way of doing this. The next step ... ICS source code :-/

Comment: Programming problems belong on [so]. Do you need a programmatic solution or are you just looking for a way to turn it off?

Comment: Either and both !!

Comment: have cut/pasted into stack overflow as well now btw

Comment: FWIW. I have raised this in the code base feature request list: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=24022